# Is autonomous dynamical system equivalent to one single higher-order ode?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

We know that a higher-order ode can be converted to dynamical system by replacing each higher-order derivative by a new variable. What about inverse problem? Does a dynamical system convert to a higher-order ode?

Comment: A dynamical system is a system of ODE. Are you asking whether a system of ODE can be converted to a single higher order ODE?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Then you have to specify that you mean by "equivalent".

Comment: I mean If I know the solution of one side, so do of the other through some one-one-correspondence mapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example, consider a system such as
$$ \dot{x} = x, \dot{y} = y $$
for which the origin is a proper node.  There is no autonomous second-order ODE
$\ddot{z} = f(z, \dot{z})$ that has a proper node: if the linearization at an equilibrium point has a double eigenvalue, it is an improper node.  So there 
can be no smooth conversion of the system to an autonomous second-order ODE.